How to mirror a dynamic website blog without changing the root domain links?
I want to mirror a dynamic website without pointing any link back to the target site.
For Example: https://www. aniwatch. mom/home-1/ this particular page is mirroring this website https://animixplay. st/ .
Can anyone explain me what technology the main site is using.
The main site (https://www. aniwatch. mom/) is based on wordpress and the target site is based on JS and core php.
You can alo checkout the view source page of (https://www. aniwatch. mom/home-1/) to figureout how is this possible.
I want to mirror a website same like the main site mirroring the target site.
